# Getting wrong day by 1 with NSComponent objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I converting this string `2016-12-14T03:59:59Z` to a NSDate using this way

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];

[formatter dateFromString:rawDate];
```

When I log this instance it's show `2016-12-14 03:59:59 +0000` but when I try to get the day from the instance using this way

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian] components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:nsDateInstance];

//Return 13
[components day];
```

And I don't know why. I've also tried using the `CurrentCalendar` but got the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Getting the day could be local time, or daylight Savings time.  Long story short, try the same thing but with noon as the time.  See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885896/nsdatecomponents-day-method-returning-wrong-day

Comment: @Putz1103 No, it's not due to daylight savings.

Comment: @rmaddy, updated my comment, sorry